# how to hide other column

Tags: mysql-workbench, vb.net-2010

In my datagridview, I just want to show other fields such as ID,LastName,FirstName, and MiddleName and i dont want to show any fields but i want it to retrieve even it's hidden. But when i specify what i just want to show in my datagridview it causes runtime error.

this is my code to load the datagridview.

```
MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select ID,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName from god.precord"

        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

        MysqlConn.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
```

then this is my code for retrieve data into textboxes

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick



    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        txtid.Text = row.Cells("ID").Value.ToString
        txtlastname.Text = row.Cells("LastName").Value.ToString
        txtfirstname.Text = row.Cells("FirstName").Value.ToString
        txtmiddlename.Text = row.Cells("MiddleName").Value.ToString
        txtaddress.Text = row.Cells("Address").Value.ToString
        txtcontactno.Text = row.Cells("ContactNo").Value.ToString
        txtgender.Text = row.Cells("Gender").Value.ToString
        dtpbirthdate.Text = row.Cells("Birthdate").Value.ToString
        txtage.Text = row.Cells("Age").Value.ToString

    End If

End Sub
```

[runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x59tI.png)

please help me this is for my thesis
thankyou in advance <3

Comment: A) Never post links or images of errors.  type/paste the error text here  B) this has nothing to do with MySql Workbench - that is a developer UI tool, not the actual DB C) if you do not specify a column (like Address) in the SQL it is not hidden - it doesnt exist! Set the Visible property to false for any column you want to hide D) if you leave the data in the DGV and let users edit it there, the control will enforce certain things like lengths, validate dates etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add hidden column into the select query to retreive the data.

Hide the column from the DataGridView instead.

```
try
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select ID,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Address from god.precord"

    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
    SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
    SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
    DataGridView1.Columns("Address").Visible = false

    MysqlConn.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()

End Try
```